# Can't add a number to variable in if-statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I was just trying to let the user type in a number and the program would add 0.25 to this number. But it says "+" is an invalid operator which cannot be true. Or is there some special rule that applies in my code?

```
//User Interface etc. is made
    double Num1 = 5.25
    double Num2 = 6.5
    if (Num1 <= 0) {
        Num2--;
        Num1 + 0.25; //here is the error according to eclipse
   }
```

Num1 and Num2 are from a JtextField and I hope this question isn't too stupid but I just don't get why I can't add this here.

Comment: you mean `Num1 += 0.25;` or `Num1  = Num1 + 0.25;`

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions :packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase

Comment: += has to be used

Comment: It is a invalid assignment operator, not an invalid operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the value of the expression(Num1 + 0.25) to any variable.

try the following ways to fix your program:

1) Num1 = Num1 + 0.25

2) Num1 += 0.25

For better understanding refer to this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Answer (score 2):

I hope you want to do this . You adding Num1+0.25 but not storing the result.

```
//User Interface etc. is made
    double Num1 = 5.25
    double Num2 = 6.5
    if (Num1 <= 0) {
        Num2--;
        Num1=Num1 + 0.25; //here is the error according to eclipse
   }
```